# Format String data - Asp core Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I would just like to know if there is a way in ASP.NET Core to allow users to enter the user name in a specific format, the format that I want is two letters then four numbers, or one letter then four numbers Ex."b4321" or "ba4321".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom validation rules.

```
       [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$|^[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}$"]
       public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you,also this is work: [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{1})\d{4}$"]